# C# Keep picturebox in form1

Tags: c#

I have a picturebox in windows form application that has the ability to move with arrowkeys. I want it to have certain limits to where it can go, specifically in the form. How do I do this? My class to move the target is below:

namespace AmazingPaintball
{
    class Target
    {
        private Point p;

```
    public Target(Point myPoi)
    {          
        p = myPoi;      
    }

    public Point Move(Keys key)
    {            
            if (key == Keys.Left)
            {
                p.Offset(-50, 0);
            }
            else if (key == Keys.Right)
            {
                p.Offset(50, 0);
            }
            else if (key == Keys.Up)
            {
                p.Offset(0, -50);
            }
            else if (key == Keys.Down)
            {
                p.Offset(0, 50);
            } 
        return p;

    }
}
```

}

Below is the form1:

namespace AmazingPaintball
{

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Random positionX = new Random();
    Random positionY = new Random();
    Target einstein;
    int count = 0;
    Paintballs pBalls = new Paintballs();
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();


    SoundPlayer wavPlayer = new SoundPlayer(@"G:\ChefBrohansPaintballFunNew\ChefBrohansPaintballFun\Resources\singlegunshot.wav");
    SoundPlayer wavPlayer2 = new SoundPlayer(@"G:\ChefBrohansPaintballFunNew\ChefBrohansPaintballFun\bin\Debug\Resources\Applause.wav");


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Point point = new Point(positionX.Next(0, 638), positionY.Next(0, 404));
        einstein = new Target(point);
        ptrEinstein.Location = point;    

    }


    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        pBalls.paint(e.Graphics);

    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {            
        ptrEinstein.Location = einstein.Move(e.KeyData);                        
        pictureBox1.Update();
        pictureBox1.Refresh();          

    }




    private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        wavPlayer.Play();
        pBalls.add(e.Location);
        pictureBox1.Refresh();                        
        count++;
    }        

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                      
        stopwatch.Start();           

    }

    private void ptrEinstein_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        count++;            
        ptrEinstein.Image = Properties.Resources.AlbertEinsteinTongue;
        stopwatch.Stop();            
        wavPlayer2.Play();
        MessageBox.Show("It took " + count + " shots and " + stopwatch.Elapsed + " seconds to hit the target");
        wavPlayer2.Stop();            
        ptrEinstein.Image = Properties.Resources.AlbertEinsteinFace;            
        count = 0;            
        stopwatch.Reset();
        stopwatch.Start();   

    }   


}
```

}

The picturebox is ptrEinstein and it is able to move in the form1_keydown event.

Comment: I edited the post so it has the code.

Answer (score 0):

When you're moving the picture box, first check to make sure where you're moving it to is inside the form. E.g. check if the new X + the width of the picture box is less than the width of the form, etc.

Comment: It is able to move in form1, but for example if I hold the right arrow key, it keeps going in that direction and off of the form itself.

Comment: To be able to give a more detailed answer I'd need to see the code that's moving the picture box. The answer is the same though: before actually moving the picture box, first check that where it would move to is valid (not off of the form)

Comment: Your problem is in Target.Move. Before changing the location, you need to make sure the new location is valid (inside the movement area.) You could do this by, say, passing in the ClientSize of the Form and size of the PictureBox to the Move function and then making sure the picture box is still inside the form.

Answer (score 0):

This will be incomplete because we do not have your code, but you should compare the clientSize properties to the picturebox location (taking into account the size of the picturebox):

```
PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();

int newX = oldX + xOffset; // xOffset is whatever you're incrementing x by
int newY = oldY + yOffset; // yOffset is whatever you're incrementing y by


if (newX < 0) {
    newX = 0;
} else if (newX > this.ClientSize.Width - pb.Width) {
    newX = this.ClientSize.Width - pb.Width;
}

if (newY < 0) {
    newY = 0;
} else if (newY > this.ClientSize.Height - pb.Height) {
    newY = this.ClientSize.Height - pb.Height;
}

// New point to move it to
Point newP = new Point(newX, newY);
```

Comment: Also needs to handle newX < 0 or newY < 0.